# Save Python Crontab without Keywords

Tags: python, python-2.7, cron

I am working with python crontab, and have the ability to save crontabs for specific users.

However the python crontab package is saving crontabs with keywords (i.e @hourly rather than 0 * * * *).  I want to save without keywords as we have a couple scripts that run on the current format of our crons.

I searched through the the package, but I couldn't figure out how to do this.  Below is the code snippet of what I have so far.  Any help is appreciated!

```
#create cron obj
cron_file_path = os.getcwd() + '/' + cron
cron_obj = CronTab(tabfile=cron_file_path, user=cron_user)

for job in cron_obj:
    print str(job)
    if not job.is_valid():
        print "Job is not valid.  Please fix and retry.\n ", str(job)
#set cron
cron_obj.write_to_user(user=cron_user)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having imported crontab try :

```
crontab.SYSTEMV = True
```